# Добавить элемент в начало массива

Tags: javascript, vue.js

push() добавляет в конец массива, а можно ли как то добавит элемент в начала массива ?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/unshift

Answer (score 0):

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  template: `
  <div>
    <input v-model="input">
    <button type="button" @click="add">Add</button>
    <ul>
      <li v-for="(item, index) in items" :key="index">{{ item }}</li>
    </ul>
  </div>`,
  data() {
    return {
      items: [
        "Aloha",
        "Hola",
      ],
      input: "",
    };
  },
  methods: {
    add() {
      if (this.input === "") {
        return;
      }
      this.items.unshift(this.input);
      this.input = "";
    },
  },
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```